# Weird javascript IE6 bug, it think it needs an extra bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-6

I'm currently developing a jQuery Plugin called Sudo Slider. (http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/)

While developing it, I just assumed that IE6 would continue to work (it stopped working in IE6 somewhere between version 2.0.1 and 2.0.8).

And now IE6 reports a bug that I just can't find.

See the bug here: http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/assets/files/SudoSlider/bug/

Hard to describe, but apparently IE6 thinks that it needs an extra bracket.

Call me a lazy developer or whatever for not checking IE6 all the time, but this project is something I do for free. And since IE6 tends to give me a headache, I tend not to open it (not when i do a paid project though).

Comment: Is there a description of the error?

Comment: do you use version control? If you do, then you should be able to bisect the source and do binary search of which version introduces the bug. Otherwise, if you do keep an archive of all minor versions, then you can do a manual bisection.

Comment: Whoo boy, the good ol' binary search for a bug. Done it (even in the last couple of months sorry to say) but usually that's only needed if you're on a team and have no idea who broke it.

Comment: @darkporter: Even in a single-man team, the last week's "you" is often a different "you" than the current "you"; binary bug search can be useful if you know you broke a code that previously work and have zero idea what changes could have broken it.

Comment: Hi, It's fine on IE8 and the closure compiler at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home says there are no errors. Good luck in trying to get Microsoft to fix this IE6 bug - lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed it now, but i still have no idea how it happened.

I replaced the:

```
if (!dontCountinueInit)
{
    ...
}
```

With exactly the same, i just rewrote the `if(..)`

Then i replaced a `if(t<0)` with `if(t < 1-1)` // Yes, i'm serious.

Then the i replaced

```
function ajaxAdjust (target, conti, ajaxCallBack) //hønse
{
    ...

};
```

With

```
function ajaxAdjust(target, conti, ajaxCallBack) {
    ...
}
```

So somehow a misalignment of the brackets made the script crash in IE6.

You can see the fixed version here:
http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/assets/files/SudoSlider/bug/fixed/

I just don't get IE6.

Answer (score 0):

just found that in your script:

//line 136

```
if (option[9] /*auto*/ ) option[11] /*continuous*/ = truev;
```

what in the world is that ?

Comment: That line break isn't supposed to be there.
But it's just a bug fix that have nothing to do with the current bug. And in general, i use the variable "truev" instead of the boolean value true, to make the minimized version smaller.